# npm install -g is waiting undefinitively, nothing happens

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm

I'm on windows, behind a proxy I've configured with `npm config set proxy http://myproxy:myport`.

When I do `npm install -g bower` nothing happens, the cursor is "rolling" (displays those chars : `-`, then `\`, `|`, `/` and then back again to `-`).

So I've entered `npm --loglevel verbose install -g bower` and then I have many downloads, and the end of the logs is this:

```
npm verb afterAdd C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\update-notifier\0.2.0\package\package.json written
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp/-/tmp-0.0.23.tgz
npm verb addTmpTarball C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-5468-42bc5663\registry.npmjs.org\tmp\-\tmp-0.0.23.tgz not in flight; adding
npm verb addTmpTarball already have metadata; skipping unpack for tmp@0.0.23
npm verb afterAdd C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\tmp\0.0.23\package\package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb afterAdd C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\tmp\0.0.23\package\package.json written
-
```

And the cursor is "rolling" here...

If I stop it using `ctrl+C` and launch it again, then npm tries again to install bower, and sticks `afterAdd` an other package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really weird: I had to stop it (`ctrl+C`) and relaunch it multiple times until it doesn't stick anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Try this If you are behind a proxy server;

- npm config set proxy "http://username:password@proxy_hostname.com:80"
- npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"
- npm config set strict-ssl false

Use second command To resolve packages by name and version, npm talks to a registry website that implements the CommonJS Package Registry specification for reading package info,sometimes node can not register it and you have to set manuelly.